# How Angular get parameter name?

Tags: javascript, angular

I just started to learn Angular, and I found this code below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    
app.controller('siteCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.runoob.com/try/angularjs/data/sites.php'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.sites;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });
  
});
```

Now this has been a bit of problem, since if I change the signature of the function in the second parameter of `app.controller` to `function($scope, myHttp)`.

It failed to work properly. But why??

Does the parameter name of `$http` matter? Doesn't it just a symbol that I can replace freely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turn out, this is some technology called `Dependency Injection`.

And Angular turn `function($scope, $http)` into a string and use regex to match its parameter name. Which in this case is `$scope` and `$http`

And then search in Angular's internal cache to determine wether or not Angular hold the instance of an object named `$scope` and `$http`

So the parameter name can't be change freely